# What do you call a person who is opposed/hates the entirety of LGBTQ+?

Tags: single-word-requests, sexual-minorities

Someone who hates homosexuals is a homophobe, someone who hates trans people is a transphobe, but I don't know a good word to describe the people that just hate anything related to progressive gender/sexuality. Maybe bigot, but the official definition doesn't sound fitting and it isn't restricted to just LGBTQ+

Comment: *LGBTQ-basher*.

Comment: As this is an English Language site I would suggest you choose your words more carefully. First, opposition is not the same as hatred. Second "progressive" is so subjective and charged as to be meaningless. It sounds as if you are not searching for word to describe something, but a slogan or tag (Fascist! Racist! Sexist! Reactionary!) to abuse someone with whom you disagree rather than using the English language to discuss or argue a point. Perhaps bigot is the right word to describe this attitude.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a **single** LGBT hate word. *Homophobe/homophobic* and *transphobe/transphobic* are used readily.

As a point of note, *homophobia* encompasses a range of negative attitudes and feelings toward homosexuality or people who are identified or perceived as being lesbian, gay, or bisexual. Not just gay.

Some, but not all, [incorporate *transphobia* into the umbrella term *homophobia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophobia), but *transphobia* does separate the bias from *homophobia* as being *transgender* involves gender rather than sexuality.

Comment: I agree - hate is a spectrum in the same way sexuality is, and it can even happen within the LGBTQ+ community (e.g. biphobia and transphobia in the gay / lesbian communities)

Comment: *"people who are identified or perceived as being lesbian, gay, or bisexual. Not just gay."* - A lot of people use the term "gay" for men and women - I have a female friend who describes herself as "gay" rather than *lesbian" (not that she says "lesbian" doesn't apply, just that she generally users the shorter word).

Answer (score 1):

How about "anti-LGBTQ+ bigot"?

> My name is Natalie Weiss and I’m a trans woman from Lincoln, Nebraska. In September of this year, I made a bit of a national stir when I lost my job for cursing at a prominent **anti-LGBTQ+ bigot** who works in my state. ([OUT magazine](https://www.out.com/commentary/2019/12/20/op-ed-what-we-lost-when-kamala-harris-dropped-out))

Answer (score 0):

There are two terms that I'm familiar with, as defined by [QMUNITY](http://qmunity.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Queer_Terminology_Web_Version__Sept_2013__Cover_and_pages_.pdf):

> **LGBT-phobia**: A term used to include all forms of homophobia, lesbophobia, biphobia and transphobia; **queerphobia** is also used.